# Laravel validation error messages string always ends with 's'

Tags: php, validation, laravel-4

I'm trying to validate my simple login form, I have rule like this :

```
public static $rules = [
    'username' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required'
];
```

and when I test it it successfully shows the error message but its end with 's'.
[image]

what does the 's' means?

Comment: it's default laravel message, i've checked in the lang/en folder about the validation message, and there's no 's' in the message

Comment: check the session and see what you get.

Comment: It's probably in your view where you iterate over the error messages. Maybe something like `{{ $error }}s` (this happens to me sometimes when I press `Ctrl+S` to save and the Ctrl key is not press properly, so it just writes an `s`).